# How does plot function find regsubsets in R?

Tags: r, class, plot, call

I'm confused about the mechanics of R (crossover from python). For example, I find best subsets with regsubsets (this is a class from a library called "leaps") and then plot below:

```
regfit_full = regsubsets(Something~.,data = db)
plot(regfit_full, scale="r2")
```

How does plot know how to deal with my instance of regsubsets class? Does plot have first look for a plot method in regsubsets first tells it how? And if this is the case, this second part confuses me. In order to look up documentation I do `?plot.regsubsets`. If plot is a method of regsubsets, why is it not `?regsubsets.plot` or something?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Read up on S3 methods in R: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot()` is a generic function in R which dispatches to the "correct" version based on the `class()` of the first parameter. All the "special" methods for `plot` can be found with `methods(plot)`.

You can learn more about is in the [Advanced R OO field guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html)